# Use of energy–momentum relation for virtual particle deriving Klein Gordon equation

Tags: forces, energy, particle-physics, momentum, mesons

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle#Properties) it is claimed that

> A virtual particle does not precisely obey the energy–momentum
> relation $m^2c^4 = E^2 − p^2c^2$

But then why is Klein Gordon relation (in the context of Yukawa theory) derived using $m^2c^4 = E^2 − p^2c^2$?

The equation that comes out should describe the exchange meson (which is a virtual particle), so does the relation hold for virtual particle in this care or not?

Comment: I don't know about the rest of the question but  the Klien-Gordan equation was originally derived by Schrodinger in an attempt to formulate QM consistent with relativity; he wasn't able to make sense of it and published his non-relativistic version instead, aka the Schrodinger equation which takes it's starting point as the classical energy-momentum relation.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the derivation of KG equation strictly in the context of Yukawa theory?

Comment: @AndreiGeanta See "Introduction to High Energy Physics" - Donald H.Perkins, chapter 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual particles exist only within the integration implied by the iconal representation of [Feynman diagrams.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)

[image: virtual]

Here the exchanged photon is virtual.

Energy and momentum are conserved by the incoming and outgoing real, on mass shell, particles. Virtual particles have the name and the quantum numbers of the  name, except they are off mass shell, according to the integration implied by the input values of the energy and momentum.

This has nothing to do with the operator representation of momentum and energy, which are part of the quantum mechanics postulates , whether one is working with Feynman diagrams or with another quantum mechanical mathematical tool. The Kline Gordon was derived by using the operator representation in special relativity of energy and momentum, but that has nothing to do with the mathematics of virtual particles.